# How do I insert HTML to a onenote page using VBA

Tags: html, vba, insert, outlook, onenote

**Background**
I use Onenote at work like a scrapbook, keeping track of assigned tasks and my progress through those tasks. Tasks are assigned via an automated email (outlook) typically these tasks involve manually reading web pages and filling in other webpages with results.

So far I've used the email arrival to trigger a VBA script which use uses data in the email to save the "requirements.html" page and the "ingredients.html" page locally. I then use python to parse and do some initial verification on the ingredients.html. This results in an augmented "requirements.html" containg colour coded status of parts.

**my question**
I've pretty much cut'n'pasted [this code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/OneNote-2010-Create-New-880f8ee3) and managed to add a new page to section X of notebook Y (where x and y are strings passed to the function) or creating a new section by copying section.one file into the notebook folder `DEST = "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\OneNote Notebooks\Tasks\" + rqst_section + ".one"`

while the code adds plain text to the page adding raw html source code in place of the plain text results in a object error when line
`oneNote.UpdatePageContent doc.XML`
is executed.
Has anyone managed to get the same result using VBA as this manual sequence,
select all text in browser window and copy 'n' paste it into a page in onenote.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to add the contents of the augmented `requirements.html` to the page?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a "UpdatePageContent" in "IApplication" failed error message, found out I had a Form Feed (chr(12) or vbFormFeed) character in a textfile I was trying to insert text into a page. Stripped that out and everything else seemed to work fine. Run the offending data through a hex editor, or strip it down little-by-little until you find the problem area.

Hope this helps.